# Mass Effect 2 savegame - Can I see which decisions I made?

Tags: mass-effect-2

Before playing ME3 I'm going through ME2 again. I'm playing as renegade Shepard since I already have a ME2 savegame with a paragon playthrough. Now, on Legion's loyalty mission, I have to decide if I want to rewrite or destroy the heretics. Problem is, I'm not sure what option I chose as paragon and as renegade I want make the opposite choice (just to see how that affects me in ME3).

Long story short, is there a way to determine which decision I made during my old playthrough? I tried a modified version of Gibbed's save editor but can't see anything related to Geth/heretics (only if the crew survived, if the Colletor base was destroyed etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to know which main decisions you made in your ME2 playthrough. You can review them when you start a new ME3 game and import an ME2 character. So what you could do is fire up ME3, "start" a new game, import your first ME2 character in and review the decisions you made there. It's the first page after you choose which career to pick.

[image: Screencap of Mass Effect 3 import page]